# Converting html entity into the equivalent string

Tags: java

Need to convert html entity into the equivalent string - I have used `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml` - but it is not working for some html code like &#539 - ț. Whereas `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml`  this works fine for -é,ù. But ț is being converted to `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try **[StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4(java.lang.String))**

```
System.out.println(org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4("&#233;")); // é
System.out.println(org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4("&#249;")); // ù
System.out.println(org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4("&#539;")); // ț
```

### See Also:

**[Character Entity Reference Chart](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref)**

Comment: Hi @Sandeep - StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4 works well for é,ù but still i am facing the problem with the letter  ț , IF I try this System.out.println(org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4("&#539;")); --> ? is getting printed in console and in my PDF screen the letter ț is skipped i mean it not getting printed in PDF. Do u have any other suggestions... ?